# Intermittent connection issue with accounts.google.com:443 ( Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to accounts.google.com:443 )

Tags: php, curl, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to connect `accounts.google.com:443` for showing visits count to application. 
Getting below error

> Google_IO_Exception: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to accounts.google.com:443 in Google_IO_Curl->executeRequest() (line 130 of /home/meme_dev/meme/meme-dev/sites/all/libraries/google-api-php-client/src/Google/IO/Curl.php).

But this is intermittent. sometime it is working sometime not.
We have checked our server side no firewall/proxy blocking.

Please help to resolve this issue

Curl File - google-api-php-client/src/Google/IO/Curl.php

```
$curl = curl_init();

if ($request->getPostBody()) {
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request->getPostBody());
}

$requestHeaders = $request->getRequestHeaders();
if ($requestHeaders && is_array($requestHeaders)) {
$curlHeaders = array();
foreach ($requestHeaders as $k => $v) {
$curlHeaders[] = "$k: $v";
}
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlHeaders);
}
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $request->getUrl());

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $request->getRequestMethod());
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $request->getUserAgent());
$proxy = 'XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX';    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

// The SSL version will be determined by the underlying library
// @see https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/pull/644
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

if ($request->canGzip()) {
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
}

$options = $this->client->getClassConfig('Google_IO_Curl', 'options');
if (is_array($options)) {
$this->setOptions($options);
}

foreach ($this->options as $key => $var) {
curl_setopt($curl, $key, $var);
}

if (!isset($this->options[CURLOPT_CAINFO])) {
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacerts.pem');
}

$this->client->getLogger()->debug(
'cURL request',
array(
'url' => $request->getUrl(),
'method' => $request->getRequestMethod(),
'headers' => $requestHeaders,
'body' => $request->getPostBody()
)
);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
watchdog('Curl response for GA', "GA response: @path", array("@path" => $response));
if ($response === false) {
$error = curl_error($curl);
$code = curl_errno($curl);
$map = $this->client->getClassConfig('Google_IO_Exception', 'retry_map');
watchdog('Curl error for GA', "GA response: @path", array("@path" => $error));
$this->client->getLogger()->error('cURL ' . $error);
throw new Google_IO_Exception($error, $code, null, $map);
}
$headerSize = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);

list($responseHeaders, $responseBody) = $this->parseHttpResponse($response, $headerSize);
$responseCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

$this->client->getLogger()->debug(
'cURL response',
array(
'code' => $responseCode,
'headers' => $responseHeaders,
'body' => $responseBody,
)
);

return array($responseBody, $responseHeaders, $responseCode);
```

Comment: Please include the full command you are trying to execute so i can test it.

Comment: I am connecting with my application via curl call. In server i am using  curl -v https://accounts.google.com:443

Comment: Welcome to stack for us to help you we need to see what you are doing for that to happen you need to include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve We cant guess what is wrong with something we cant see.    curl -v accounts.google.com:443 has nothing to do with Google analytics api please edit your question and  include your code

Comment: Updated my questions

Comment: have you checked this https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/issues/94

Comment: Yes.  by adding $this->SetOpt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4); & CURLOPT_SSLVERSION

Comment: Any suggestion for the above issue